# How to Determine if a Primary Key in Table 1 does not Appear in Table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

How to tell if  primary key of one table is not in the current table

```
item                        (current table) category_item                                            
-------|--- ----           ----------------|------------|----------
item_id          item          category_item_id| category_id|  item_id 
2119                          1                   16           2090
        ^primary key                                     ^foreign key
```

I need a query that tells me that there is no record in the "category_item" table , that has the foreign key  of any record table "item" category_item.item_id

In laymans terms I want to find out all record in "item" that do not have a "category" assigned to it.

This is true, where we cannot find any record in "category_item" that has the primary key of any of the records in table "ITEM" in the

category_item.item_i

The SELECT would item.item_id where get for e.g.

```
2113  
2110   
2310
```

each of which has no categories assigned yet.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow from pointing to the duplicates.

WHERE [column] NOT IN.  ... is the key

```
   SELECT item_id. 
    FROM item. 
    WHERE media_type LIKE '%audio%'. 
    AND item_id BETWEEN 4999 and 9000. 
    AND item_id NOT IN (  
    SELECT item_id. 
    FROM category_item. 
    ). 
    ORDER BY. 
    item.item_id;

```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `not exists`?

```
select i.item_d
from items i
where not exists (select 1 from category_item ci where ci.item_id = i.item_id);
```